# How to properly send a JSON message (using kafka) to a Jdbc Sink (Sql server)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am a little new to using kafka. I have a simple JSON message I am trying to write to SQL server (using a Sink Connector). Here is my simple JSON message:

```
{
  "DagId": "chat-bot-process-v1.0",
  "RunId": "scheduled__2021-07-25T10:00:00+00:00",
  "ChatKey": "82a4daf8-c1be-4524-bb80-ec252b38c020",
  "ConversationId": "2158db2e-0bcc-48e6-a96e-3347e156a90a",
  "EventTimestamp": null,
  "EventType": "ASYNC",
  "MessageType": "EPORTWEB",
  "LastUpdateDatetime": "2022-09-21T17:05:51.473-04:00"
}
```

As you can tell, there is not a 'schema' or 'payload' structure
e.g.

```
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "dagid"
      },
   ...
  "payload": {
    "dagid": "live-person-process-v1.0",
   }
}
```

However, I was reading in the Docs (https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/) and it says **You cannot use plain JSON, CSV, etc with the JDBC Sink connector**

So I am thinking I need to add this 'schema' structure and have the JSON nested in the 'payload'.

My question is, what is the best way to do that? I have read through documentation that say I can use Avro, JSONSchemaConverter, or JSONConverter. Do I need to add this in my java code? (Could you please provide an example of using one of them for my use case?)

I can also add my Sink Connector configuration, or my Java Producer Configuration, if that helps. Thank you.

Documentation I have read that I think applies:

- https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-connectors-guide
- https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/
- https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html#connector
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/#non-json-data-jsonconverter

Answer (score 0):

> best way to do that

Well, you could [wrap your JSON value in a `payload` object, then add `schema`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonSchema.java#L61-L66). But that is not ideal because then it consumes more space in the topic as every event includes a schema.

> read through documentation that say I can use Avro, JSONSchemaConverter, or JSONConverter

You could also use Protobuf... Also, the first two options require you to run a Schema Registry server. But assuming you wanted to do that, yes, you [add dependencies to your code](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-clients/java/current/overview.html#ak-java) such as `kafka-avro-serializer` dependency (or protobuf, or jsonschema), then you change your `value.serializer` property in the producer config, accordingly.

You can refer the Avro or Protobuf documentation itself for how to setup your project to generate Java POJOs from schema files that your producer can
use.